# Forming Disjoint-Sets of nodes of MST

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, disjoint-sets

I have been  N nodes and N-1 edges,basically undirected acyclic MST.
I want to basically count number of disjoint set of nodes.
Two nodes belong to set if they have same parent and and degree of nodes are same. For eg. In the given tree . {3,4} belongs to same set because `parent[3]=1` and `parent[4]=1` and `degree[3]=degree[4]=1 ;`  {5} and {2}  also forms disjoint set ,because parent[2]=parent[5]=1 but `degree[5]=2 and degree[2]=3` . I have to count total number of disjoint sets . I have been trying doing with structure something like :

```
`define MAX 100000

int set;

struct parent
{       
int z[MAX-1];       
}

p_data[MAX];
`
```

But as it is showing p_data array very big . So please help .What kind of of data structure or logic I should follow to count total number of disjoint sets defined above.

I am unable to post image here: So please refer to this image :  http://postimage.org/image/sw2nrciib/

PLEASE SOMEONE TELL NUMBER OF DISJOINTS SET THAT CAN BE PERFORMED